# Why can't I login to my google+ account in Minion rush?

Tags: despicable-me-minion-rush

I have 2 devices. On one device I can see 2 buttons to register/login as facebook or google play games. 
On the other device I can't see these buttons. All the rest is there, only the register buttons are missing.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely it's because you don't have updated either Google Play Services or the game itself. You can update Services through [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms).

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem on a device that used to be mine, that I was setting up with a different profile for my daughter. It wouldn't give me connection options. I uninstalled and put her in as an 18 year old, and then it gave the social media options.

**TL;DR:** maybe it's set to too young an age